# Release my ionic 3 app on testflight on app store if i can do it on windows

Tags: ionic-framework, testflight

Can i release my ionic app to testflight app on app store without having a mac? Can i do it on my windows and if not how to release my ionic app to be tested without ionic serve ? please any help

Answer (score 0):

No. that is not possible. You need to have a mac to publish an IOS application.

If you want to test your application with IOS users, you can use [**Ionic View**](https://ionicframework.com/pro/view).